# Regex or condition for text in r

Tags: r, regex, logical-operators, or-condition

I have a text suppose

```
1) "Project:ABC is located near CBA, being too far from city  "
2) "P r o j e c t : PQR is located near RQP, highlights some greenary"
```

I want to extract text between the word "**project**" and "**,**" so that my output is"`ABC is located near CBA`" from **text1** and "`PQR is located near RQP`" from **text2**, for that I used regex

```
x="Project:ABC is located near CBA, being too far from city  "
sub(".*Project: *(.*?) *, .*", "\\1", x)
O\P
ABC is located near CBA
```

But for **text2)** it doesn't gives proper output so how do I include OR condition so that my both condition is satisfied. Any suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: You don't need an OR condition or something. You only need to apply space matching between letters of `project` `p *r *o *j *e *c *t *: *(.*?),`

Comment: You may as well try `regmatches(x, regexpr("^(?:Project|P r o j e c t ):\\s*\\K[^,]*", x, perl=TRUE))`. `|` means OR inside groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your regex a bit more flexible: `[^:]+:\s*([^,]+),.*`

```
> sub("[^:]+:\\s*([^,]+),.*", "\\1", "P r o j e c t : PQR is located near RQP, highlights some greenary")
[1] "PQR is located near RQP"
```

and

```
> sub("[^:]+:\\s*([^,]+),.*", "\\1", "Project:ABC is located near CBA, being too far from city  ")
[1] "ABC is located near CBA"
```

Comment: Yes this worked for all my cases..Thanks @Marc Lambrichs for your effort and time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some regex expression with Lookahead and Lookbehind assertion.

Using `stringr` package on a small example

```r
Vec <- c("Project:ABC is located near CBA, being too far from city", 
         "P r o j e c t : PQR is located near RQP, highlights some greenary")
library(stringr)
str_extract(Vec, "(?<=:).*(?=,)")
#> [1] "ABC is located near CBA"  " PQR is located near RQP"
```

If your input is more complexe, regex should be adapted, as it may not be enough  restrictive (currently, it is anything between first `:` and last `,`)

Comment: your code doesn't work for this text :- "Project: Ganga gnd A3 And 3.., Plot Bearing / CTS / Survey / Final Plot No.:  Sr No 305 P , 30 P and 33 P , ag adan udruk, Tauka Mua,r Pun at Pun (M Corp.), Pun C, Pun, 411001;""

Comment: Yes the regex must be adapted to your input. Assuming their is no `,` in the text you want to extract, you can replace `.*` with `[^,]*`. `str_extract(Vec, "(?<=:)[^,]*(?=,)")` is better ?

Answer (score 0):

One option in `base R` is `gsub` to match characters (`.*`) until the `:` followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) or (`|`) a `,` followed by other characters and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub(".*:\\s*|,.*", "", Vec)
#[1] "ABC is located near CBA" "PQR is located near RQP"
```

If we need to match `Project` followed by `:`

```
pat <- paste0(gsub("", "\\\\s*", "Project"), ":\\s*|\\s*,.*")
gsub(pat, "", Vec)
#[1] "ABC is located near CBA" "PQR is located near RQP" "Ganga gnd A3 And 3.."
```

#### data

```
Vec <- c("Project:ABC is located near CBA, being too far from city", 
 "P r o j e c t : PQR is located near RQP, highlights some greenary", 
 "Project: Ganga gnd A3 And 3.., Plot Bearing / CTS / Survey / Final Plot No.: Sr No"
 )
```

Comment: Did you notice `project`?

Comment: @revo I thought it is a general pattern, thanks, I updated

Comment: @akrun your code doesn't work for this "Project: Ganga gnd A3 And 3.., Plot Bearing / CTS / Survey / Final Plot No.:  Sr No"

Answer (score 0):

If `Project` word is not a concern:

```
> text
[1] "Project:ABC is located near CBA, being too far from city  "
> substr(text,grep(":",strsplit(text,'')[[1]]),grep(",",strsplit(text,'')[[1]]))
[1] ":ABC is located near CBA,"
> substr(text,grep(":",strsplit(text,'')[[1]])+1,grep(",",strsplit(text,'')[[1]])-1)
[1] "ABC is located near CBA"
> text <- "P r o j e c t : PQR is located near RQP, highlights some greenary"
> substr(text,grep(":",strsplit(text,'')[[1]])+1,grep(",",strsplit(text,'')[[1]])-1)
[1] " PQR is located near RQP"
```

should work fine!